# I want my string to converted to a day

Tags: java, locale

I have this string

```
String s = "29/04/2015"
```

And I want it to produce the name of that day in my language, which is Norwegian.

For example:

- `29/04/2015` is "Onsdag"
- `30/04/2015` is "Torsdag"

How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry, i have no sample code.

Comment: You need a locale specific DateFormat.  This is an easy problem.

Comment: Do you have a code example?

Comment: If you don't have a sample code at least tell us what you have tried so far. Don't expect that someone here will just write all the code for you. We are eager to help but first show us that you have actually tried something before posting.

Comment: Try locale specific date format - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat-java.lang.String-java.text.DateFormatSymbols-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String dateString = "29/04/2015";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E", Locale.no_NO);
String day = formatter.format(date);
```

Now `day` will have the day in given locale. Update

Comment: hm.. am updating my answer

Comment: getDay() from Date has been deprecated since 1.1 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay%28%29. Need to use Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY).

Comment: @Trobbins a switch can be used to return the String version of the day of the week. OP didn't want an int they wanted the actual name of the day of the week.

Comment: @BarbiePylon updated my answer with `SimpleDateFormat` now no need to have switch cases.

Comment: I am not sure why, but `Locale.no_NO` doesn't compile for me.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need a `Calendar` object.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();    
String s = "29/04/2015"
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
cal.setTime(format.parse(s));
```

From the `Calendar` you can get the day of the week.

```
int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

dayOfWeek will be 1-7 with Sunday (*in english*) being 1

Comment: I just tested this, Sunday starts from 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure an instance of DateFormat, with your locale, (take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

then parse the Date and get the day, as Dilip already suggests.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to parse the `String` to a `Date`. Then use a `Calendar` to get the day of the week. You can use an array to convert it to the appropriate string.

```
// Array of Days
final String[] DAYS = {
   "søndag", "mandag", "tirsdag", "onsdag", "torsdag", "fredag", "lørdag"
};

// Parse the date
final String source = "27/04/2015";
final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date date = new Date();
try {
   date = format.parse(source);
} catch (final ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

// Convert to calendar
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);
final int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

// Get the day's name
System.out.println("Day of Week: " + dayOfWeek);
System.out.println("Day = " + DAYS[dayOfWeek - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final int SUNDAY = 1;
final int ONSDAG = 2;
final int TORSDAG = 3;
....
....

String s = "29/04/2015";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(s);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

String dayString;
switch (day) {
     case(ONSDAG):
         dayString = "ONSDAG";
         break;
        ....
}
```

EDIT: I just tested this and it actually starts from Sunday, and returns the value of 1 for sunday, I've changed the constant values to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use date parsing combined with Locale settings to get the desired output. For e.g. refer following code.

```
String dateStr = "29/04/2015";

SimpleDateFormat dtf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date dt = dtf.parse(dateStr);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dt);
String m = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG_FORMAT, new Locale("no", "NO"));

System.out.println(m);
```

For more information about locale, visit [Oracle Java Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to *parse* your text with date to `Date` instance and then *format* it back to text. You can do it with `SimpleDateFormat` class which supports many patterns of dates like

- `dd/MM/yyyy` for your original date,
- and `EEEE` for full name of day in month.

While formatting you will also need to specify locale you want to use. To create Norway specific locale you can use for instance

```
Locale nor = Locale.forLanguageTag("no-NO");
```

So your code can look more or less like:

```
String text = "29/04/2015";

Locale nor = Locale.forLanguageTag("no-NO");

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", nor);
SimpleDateFormat dayOfWeek = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", nor);

Date date = sdf.parse(text);
System.out.println(dayOfWeek.format(date));
```

Output: `onsdag`.

Answer (score -4):

You can use an HashMap map where the first parametri is the date "29/4/2015" while the second is the meaning. You can use your string to get the meaning map.get (yourString).

Comment: OP just used that as an example and needs a solution to get the day of the week regardless of the date.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the question